# Picking a suitable performance metric when comparing the same model but using different sets of training data (Causal inference model)

Tags: predictive-models, model-selection, aic, bic, causalimpact

I am comparing the same models prediction accuracy (Causal Impact) using different control variables as predictors and looking for a metric to decide which set of controls to use. Reading into AIC and BIC I gather they are used to compare *different* models on the *same* training data, not the other way around. I have 2 questions:

1. My learning on BIC has shown that it allows to compare between different variables that have the same sample size, does that mean it would be suitable to compare different sets of control variables as inputs, provided they are from the same time range?
2. If neither AIC or BIC are suitable criterion/metrics, could someone point me in the direction of one that is? Preferably a metric from this list as this is what I have immediate access to. [image]

Comment: Statistics (AIC, BIC, etc.) cannot tell you about your causal assumptions, backdoor paths, selection biases, and differential measurement errors.

Comment: Understood, just for clarification would you be able to advise which of the metrics on the associated image above would be most suitable to compare the same model but using different sets of predictor variables as inputs?